# How  can I change the default crontab editor 

Tags: linux, cron

Can I change the default crontab editor to `vi` editor? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time I do something like:

```
# env EDITOR=vi crontab -e
```

or

```
# env VISUAL=vi crontab -e
```

Answer (score 1):

setting your env to use vi will only pertain to your user account

to change it system wide for all users, on a debian based distro use this command-

update-alternatives --config editor