# What is the correct way of getting crontab on CentOS 6?

Tags: cron, centos6

I have a server running CentOS 6.2 minimal, but it doesn't appear to have crontab installed by default?

```
crontab -e
-bash: crontab: command not found
```

In searching google, I found references to a "vixie-cron" and "anacronda" but no complete answer on what the official/supported way of getting cron to work on CentOS 6 is.

Maybe someone can shed some light on this?

update:

```
rpm -qf `which crontab`
/usr/bin/which: no crontab in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)
rpm: no arguments given for query
```

Comment: You can't `which` something that doesn't exist on your host.  I think what you are looking for is `yum provides */crontab`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
# rpm -qf `which crontab`
cronie-1.4.4-7.el6.x86_64
```

Vixie-cron was [replaced](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/ch04s14.html) with [Cronie](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Automating_System_Tasks.html) in EL6. Likely it wasn't installed in your "minimal" installation; they really do strive to be minimal with it.

Comment: Thanks, `yum install cronie` seems to have done the trick. Do you know how to set which editor `crontab -e` uses by default?

Comment: That's a separate question. [Read it here](http://serverfault.com/q/197741/126632).

Comment: It looks like I also have to do `service crond start` and `chkconfig crond on`, regarding this question. Thanks for the other answer, got it working.